# Need Assistance with one click button

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I have a site with multiple and users and i want to build a feature but i don't know how to make a button that when you click it one time you can't click it anymore, once you click it, it runs the function and just disappears like something that shows in database so it will happen to all users.

Comment: This question is way too broad. Please try something yourself first and when you run into some _specific_ issue, come back, show us what you've tried, the expected behaviour and the actual behaviour. From there, we will probably be able to help you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please step first to [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/g35m6q4w/ Hope this will help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You want a button that disappears when clicked:

```
<button onclick="this.style.display = 'none';">Click me!</button>
```

That should do it. If you also want it to run a function, do this:

```
<button onclick="this.style.display = 'none';myFunction();">Click me!</button>
```

Where `myFunction()` is your javascript function.